# How to find generator for intersection of two large subgroups (permutations in $S_{13}$)?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, finitely-generated

I have

$$\sigma = ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 )( 6, 10 )( 7, 11 )( 8, 12 )( 9, 13 ),$$

$$\tau = ( 2, 5 )( 3, 4 )( 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 )$$

as my two permutations that generate $G$.

How would I find the generator of the intersection of $$H = \langle \sigma \rangle$$  and $$K = \langle \tau \rangle$$

Would I have to find all the elements of $H$ and $K$ and see which elements coincide or is there a more efficient way (since the permutations are not that small). I wasn't quite understanding some of the other explanations here on the site. Thank you for all of the help!

Comment: Thank you Robert. Could you elaborate on why we need to check which powers of $\sigma$ send 2 to 5 please?

Comment: Where does $\tau$ send $2$?

Comment: It sends 2 to 5.

Comment: So if the intersection is trivial, the generator is just the identity permutation?

Comment: Can an element of $H$ send $2$ anywhere else and hope to result in an element of $K$?

Comment: Actually, see my answer below, as corrected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122767/discussion-between-corgilover123-and-robert-shore).

Comment: These subgroups have orders $8$ and $10$. Those orders are not large, they are tiny! You should be able to solve this problem in your head. Large starts at about order $10^9$. You may be interested to know that it can be proved using  Babai's recent breakthrough on the graph isomorphism problem that generators of the intersection of two arbitrary subgroups of $S_n$ defined by generating sets can be computed in quasipolynomial time.

Answer (score 4):

Since $\vert \sigma \vert = 10$ and $\vert \tau \vert = 8$, the only possibilities for $\vert H \cap K \vert$ are $1$ and $2$.  That's because $H \cap K$ is a subgroup of $H$ and of $K$, so its order must divide both $10= \vert H \vert$ and $8= \vert K \vert$, so $\vert H \cap K \vert \mid \gcd(10, 8)=2$.

That means the intersection can only be non-trivial if $\sigma^5 \in K$ and $\tau^4 \in H$.  It's pretty easy to see (by calculation) whether that happens.  Since it does, that element, along with the identity element, has to be the entire intersection.